# Redirect user after all files finished uploading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery-File-Upload with Carrierwave for multiple file upload. I am uploading multiple files and would like to redirect user after all files are uploaded. This is how I am doing it for now:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_update').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_update').append(data.context)
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

      $("#submit_button").on 'click', ->
        data.submit()

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

At the moment I just display all progress bars at the same page and after all files are uploaded I am still on the same page. How can I know when all files are uploaded so I can redirect user to another page? Thanks :)

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558389/jquery-fileupload-plugin-success-call-back) might help

Answer (score 1):

```
completed: function(e, data) {
  //redirect in here
}
```

[Blueimp API - fileupload options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)